# How to change image url parameters?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can i change image url parameters?

Example:

```
http://www.example.com/random1/random2/random3/nameofimage.jpg
```

In random will be random letters and numbers.

I don't have any idea how to do it, if you could help me I thank you

Comment: Where are your parameters of `image url`?

Comment: What exactly do you have and what exactly are your trying to do? Your description is very vague, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP you can use concatenation to create the url like this:

```
$randomValue = stackoverflow;

$url = "http://www.example.com/" . $randomValue . "/random2/random3/nameofimage.jpg";

echo $url;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the form to upload an image or file, you can change the file name before you upload the file.

First get posted file and change the name. Then upload the file.

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp); // Random name
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/images/" . $newfilename);
```

Let's say your random image name is `lol123.jpg`.

Your image is now in: `http://www.example.com/images/lol123.jpg`

You want to get that image with something like this?: `http://www.example.com/haha/123/blahblah/lol123.jpg`

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^haha/123/blahblah/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ images/$1
```

When you visit `http://www.example.com/haha/123/blahblah/lol123.jpg`, that will show the image: `http://www.example.com/images/lol123.jpg`

Comment: yes i know this, i would like to show the image with this random parameters (there is not a folder), i think it is .htaccess

Comment: Are you uploading your images via a form?

Comment: yes, my images is in a folder, called IMAGES. So, i need to show image using a url and i would for example: www.example.com/324324/kokokok/432434/myimagename.jpg (but i don't want to create 3 folders. Look i found a system that i want. Access this website: http://promoface.store/534543543543/cascascascas/632451698075.jpg   (you can use random numbers and letters, it will show the same image)

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me how to use this part "haha/123/blahblah/" with random letters and numbers? Example: "hihi/4343434/dasdasdas", without fixed letters and numbers,